# Magento2.2.5 admin panel not able to get to cms page or static blocks

Tags: magento2, error

when I go into the admin panel and then try to get to any CMS page or static block (in the admin panel) I get a 500 error which is the below error. Also in the admin panel if I try to go to any cart price rule the below error occurs.

Also on the site when you go to any category the top category image does not seem to load.

When I look in the server logs I see the error:

```
Uncaught exception 'Error' with message 'Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Config\ReaderInterface' in /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111
```